# Query MySQL from Powershell (Connect-MySqlServer)

Tags: mysql, powershell

I am trying to READ some rows from a local mysql database but I cannot. I have tried to install MysqlCmlets with the following command:

```
 Install-Module -Name MySQLCmdlets
```

A yellow progress bar appears at the top and then it seems to finish/stop running with no errors, warnings or questions. I then try to use MySQL commands such as "Connect-MySqlServer" and I get the error:

```
The term 'Connect-MySqlServer' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program.
```

I restarted powershell after installing, I even restarted my computer and it doesnt works.
The "MySQL" folder is in C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules and it contains the proper files such as "Connect-MySqlServer". I also checked and "PsModulePath" has that path properly set as well. I also tried to run the install with -Force and to use an msi file from adata to install it, yet powershell keeps giving me the same error.

As suggested in another post I also tried

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

And installed again and still no go.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to import the module after installing it. i.e.

```
Import-module MySQLCmdlets
```

By default Starting in PowerShell 3.0, installed modules are automatically imported to the session when you use any commands or providers in the module. **However**, you still need to use the Import-Module command to import a module if you disableld automatic module importing using the `$PSModuleAutoloadingPreference` preference variable.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module?view=powershell-5.1